# How to Rip Foreign VCD's that has Dual Audio Language Tracks?

Tags: ripping, vcd

I just started to clean out my old VCD collection and wanted to rip them to my hard drive. The problem is that its all Chinese VCD cartoons which has dual audio tracks. A mandarin and cantonese track. I tried looking around for a VCD ripper that can rip these .DAT files and isolate only 1 audio stream. I tried the program Handbrake and VCDGear, but they rip the entire video track with both languages heard at once. I want to be able to just rip 1 audio stream so my kids can easily click on the file and watch them without having to fiddle with the left and right audio selections.

Is there a program that can do this without having to go through a bunch of steps?

Thanks!

Comment: why not use a player that allows automatic language settings so no choices have to be made post-play?

Comment: because it needs to be able to be played on portable mp4 players. its for kids. needs to be as easy as one click play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i ended up doing is use the sonyvegas video editor software. My steps to extract and isolate the audio on old VCDs was this:

1. Copy the .DAT or .MPG file to your computer from your VCD.
2. Import the file into the Sony Vegas software.
3. Right click on the audio track and find the plugin: isolate + clone to both audio channels.
4. Render as MP4 format and save.
5. Thats it!

I had to do this manually one at a time and couldnt find any way to do this in bulk.